# DAX moving average not working

Tags: powerbi, dax, moving-average

I try to calculate moving average in DAX power bi. I use different codes, for example this.

```
    Moving AverageX 7B Days = 
    AVERAGEX (
    DATESINPERIOD( 
    sahkoInput[Date];
    LASTDATE ( sahkoInput[Date]);
    -7;
    DAY
    );
    sahkoInput[price]
    )
```

All codes give the same result - Moving AverageX 7B Days is equal to column "price". What went wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would look to add a date/calendar table to your data model.
This can be as simple as a list of consecutive dates from at least seven days before your first data point until after the end of when you expect your last one to be.
The reason for this is that the date functions in DAX always work best when they have a table of consecutive dates to look at - you can get unpredictable results when your fact table doesn't have any data on a particular date.

Once you have added the date table, create a relationship to link the date column in your sahkoInput table to the date column in your date table.

Now, the following measure should work:

```
    Moving AverageX 7B Days = 
    CALCULATE (
               AVERAGE('sahkoInput'[Price]);
               DATESINPERIOD ('DateTable'[Date];
                               LASTDATE ('DateTable'[Date]);
                               -7;
                               DAY)
              )
```

Comment: Becomes more clear, it was what was online. But my date is date and hour, so one day has 24 hours and 24 records. Is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

Create a date table, this will dramatically improve performance and increase readability. You can do that by using the following DAX:

```
Min Date := MIN('sahkoInput'[Date])
Max Date := MAX('sahkoInput'[Date])

Dates :=
    VAR BaseCalendar =
        CALENDAR ( [Min Date], [Max date] )
    RETURN
        GENERATE (
            BaseCalendar,
            VAR BaseDate = [Date]
            VAR YearDate =
                YEAR ( BaseDate )
            VAR MonthNumber =
                MONTH ( BaseDate )
            RETURN
                ROW (
                    "Day", BaseDate,
                    "Year", YearDate,
                    "Month Number", MonthNumber,
                    "Month", FORMAT ( BaseDate, "mmmm" ),
                    "Year Month", FORMAT ( BaseDate, "mmm yy" )
                )
        )
```

Then referencing this date table you can create an average using the standard average function, like so:

```
Moving Average 7 Days :=
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( 'sahkoInput'[Price] );
    KEEPFILTERS ( DATESINPERIOD ( 'Dates'[Date]; MAX ( 'Dates'[Date] ); -7; DAY ) )
)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Becomes more cleat, it was what was online. But my date is date and hour, so one day has 24 hours and 24 records. Is that ok?

Comment: I don't think there will be an issue if your type is datetime vs shortdate, try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: If I use code from here https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/how-to-build-a-calendar-table-with-date-and-time/td-p/241728, it gives me error "Column 'Date' in Table 'DateTime' contains a duplicate value '1/1/2015' and this is not allowed for columns on the one side of a many-to-one relationship or for columns that are used as the primary key of a table."

Comment: The code I gave you for the date/calendar table should work just fine.

Comment: Sorry for questions, I am completely new. So how should I add datetime? For just date i add CALENDAR ( DATE(2016;1;1); DATE(2016;12;31)). How should i mark it with time? PowerBi doesn't have functions for time. Thank you again for conversation.

Comment: No worries, just accept my answer if it helped ;) as for the date formatting, I am not sure but you can try to format a Date as a DATETIME like so: FORMAT('DateTable'[date], "Long Time").

Comment: I still can't do it :) This format as in message doesn't work and among function of DAX there are not datetime or long time. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/679.power-bi-dax-date-and-time-functions.aspx

Comment: Did you need the hours and minutes? It should not affect your calculation.